# aiogram echo bot не отвечает на сообщения ошибок не выдает

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот, pycharm

aiogram echo bot не отвечает на сообщения ошибок не выдает

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, executor, types

TOKEN_API = ''

bot = Bot(TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.message):
    await message.answer(text=message.text)

if __name__ == '__name__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Вы токен отправляете, или пустая строка? Покажите как выглядит консоль при запуске

Comment: токен не скину но он есть  ссылка на консоль - https://imgur.com/a/bz9VG8y

Answer (score 1):

У вас не работает бот, потому что вы его не запускаете.

Бот, в свою очередь, не запускается потому что не срабатывает условие

```
if __name__ == '__name__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Условие не срабатывает потому что `__name__` в вашем случае равно `__main__`

Попробуйте:

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, executor, types

TOKEN_API = ''

bot = Bot(TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.message):
    await message.answer(text=message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```